# How to reload php.ini on win10?

Tags: php, apache, windows-10, phar

I am working on website software, that makes phar archives, however the website is showing exception.

I've tried to edit php.ini as it says exception. But there were no any changes after restarting apache server. I also tried to reload php.ini configuration using php.exe --ini command

My code:

```php
$phar = new Phar(getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "projects" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $plugin->projectId . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $plugin->description["name"] . ".phar");
$phar->buildFromDirectory(getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "projects" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $plugin->projectId . "raw");
```

In php.ini I have this

```
phar.readonly = 0
```

I also tried to set it to Off, same problem...

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: creating archive "D:/JetBrains/PhpstormProjects/PPM/projects/BPCore-12636-1567109326/BPCore.phar" disabled by the php.ini setting phar.readonly in D:\JetBrains\PhpstormProjects\PPM\export.php:18

Stack trace:
#0 D:\JetBrains\PhpstormProjects\PPM\export.php(18): Phar->__construct('D:\\JetBrains\\Ph...')
#1 {main} thrown in D:\JetBrains\PhpstormProjects\PPM\export.php on line 18
```

Comment: code up a page with only `<?php phpinfo();?>`  and look for the path to the `php.ini` file that is actually being used, then change that one and restart Apache

Comment: I've [tried it already](https://i.ibb.co/ZXSw09w/image.png). It shows that phar.readonly is turned on, but in php.ini is it set to 0...